# Restriction on org.eclipse.ui.internal.* classes

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

we are developing a Modeling Environment as a plugin for Eclipse. Within this environment it should be possible for the user to modify one of the provided perspectives, i.e. hide/show items in the Coolbar, Menubar and views. It appeared to be difficult to modify the visible Coolbar-/MenuItems when you are not developing an entire RCP-Application but only a Plugin. 
The only solution I was able to come up with was to add an access rule in the Java build path to make the org.eclipse.ui.internal.* packages available and then access the items with the CoolbarManager/MenuManager as in the following example:

```
WorkbenchWindow workbenchWin = (WorkbenchWindow)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
ICoolBarManager coolbarManager = workbenchWin.getCoolBarManager2();
IContributionItem[] items = coolbarManager.getItems();
for(IContributionItem item : items) {
    item.setVisible(false);
}
```

However, adding this access rule and then suppressing the "restriction" warnings on every call to these packages seems to a bit dirty.

Hence my question: Why are these packages restricted and is there a better way to do this?

Thanks,
Leo

Comment: The restrictions are described [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html)

Comment: A lot of menu items can be shown / hidden using the options in Customize Perspective.

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you for the link. So using the internal classes is not recommended. Do you know of any better solution to the problem? The perspective should be customised through the source code, according to an underlying eCore model.

Comment: You could look at the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point which lets you turn on / off menu items and other things using patterns. See various existing SO questions.

Comment: Unforunately activities are not a suitable solution in our case, since we have several dozens auf items that should be showed/hidden independently. That would result in several dozens different activities and therewith pretty much mess up the plugin.xml